# I keep getting this error for the colorgram module in Python

Tags: python

I keep getting this error when I am working with colorgram:

> Module 'colorgram' has no 'extract' member

Here is my code so far:

```
import colorgram

colors = colorgram.extract("hirst/hirst.jpg", 84)
```

Comment: Why did you expect that the `colorgram` module has a function called `extract`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It [appears to](https://github.com/obskyr/colorgram.py). Maybe the wrong library was download, or you have an old version?

Comment: What does `dir(colorgram)` show?

Comment: Do you have another file in the same directory called `colorgram`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I actually downloaded this module into the file and then i moved the file into a folder. I then redownloaded the module again after moving the file. But i never uninstalled it. The extract function does exist.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have installed colorgram module.
In PyCharm it is:
PyCharm/Preferences/Project/Python interpreter
If you cant see colorgram module there, use "+" to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be passing the incorrect path. I was  also getting the same error. I noticed that my dir in VS code terminal was 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\100DaysPythonBootcamp' so when i passed my file name 'image.jpg' it showed error as it was looking for it in the bootcamp folder
in this case you pass the location within you directory i.e
'Day18_Turtle\hriste-painting\image.jpg' (in my case) which was within it then i ran successfully